# Copy file path utility (GUI) required

Tags: filemanager

I use ubuntu 12.04. I am in need of a copy file path utility in ubuntu. I need to often copy the below for my tasks:

- full Filename
- Full file path

Just as an example only, in my office PC (running WIN-XP), i use a small tool from bullzip. [Link to website](http://www.bullzip.com/products/cfn/info.php). I am mentioning it here only for giving an example.

But for my ubuntu,I would be glad if someone guided me to a similar GUI based tool or an equivalent script in Nautilus. I searched a lot on the internet and i found out tools to copy files and folders but not file-paths.

Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you need any extensions or extra tools for that in Ubuntu. In nautilus, if you right click a file and paste to a text editor you will get the full path to that file, similarly for folders, also, if you right click a file and select properties, in the basic tab you can copy the filename and location.

If you select multiple files and select copy, then paste to a text editor you will get the full paths to the selected files, you can use your text editor's search and replace feature to strip away the path names and you will have only file names remaining.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply and for ur time...This does help me to some extent....